# How to I overwrite other Facebook javascript SDK?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-events

I am creating an app for Shopify and I am loading Facebook Javascript SDK on their pages. But those pages might have apps that do the same and in most cases other apps overwrite my code.

How can I make the SDK with my app ID load and be used over the others ?

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
  FB.init({
    appId: 'MY_APP_ID',
    autoLogAppEvents: true,
    xfbml: true,
    version: 'v3.0'
  });
};

(function (d, s, id) {
      let js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s);
      js.id = id;
      js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/" + locale + "/sdk.js";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Comment: You can’t. The SDK is not made to be used one the same page with multiple app ids. Its first come, first serve - if someone else embedded and initialized it for their app id before you, then you’re out.

Comment: @CBroe I don't think that this is true. I added my own code directly to the theme of this site after body tag: https://men-jewlery.myshopify.com/collections/frontpage/products/diamond-ring And one app loads its script after the page is loaded. And still their app code is being rendered, not mine.

Comment: Haven’t checked the details of how exactly that other app is embedded there (since the default code to load the SDK is async, it might not depend purely on “source code order”), but the fact remains, the whole thing is not build to be used with multiple app ids in a single page. The `FB` object is global, so it can only be initialized for one app id at a time.

Comment: So even if it lets you initialize it for your app after another app has done that already, you would pretty much “kick out” that other app at this point - most likely without that other app even being aware, so in the worst case it will still use `FB` and to call its methods trying to do what it does, but suddenly that happens “as” your app …

Comment: @CBroe my goal is to kick out the other app. I want to overwrite the init and use my app instead. But as I do so, the other app somehow catches the event and loads It's code again. How do they do that ?

Comment: Well go check their code …? (If that’s even what is actually happening, so far it sounds more it was merely what you _assume_ was going on?)

Comment: @CBroe their code is uglified and minified. I try to initiate my own app in the console, but their code reloads. I can confirm that.

Comment: _“I try to initiate my own app in the console”_ - well most likely simply to late already then, if their embedding of the SDK happened during page load already. Let me repeat: You are on the wrong way. There is no way provided to “kick out” an already initialized app. Tell the people who want to use _your_ app, that they will need to remove the other one first then.